# how to Properly use a callback function to move a unity object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I apoligise if this has been asked before but I haven't been able to find a clear enough answer on the subject. I have wrote the code below to output to the unity log but im not sure how to output its values and assign them to the player.

I am trying to move the location of a game object based the location values(xpoint, ypoint, zpoint) set by the Show Message Class. How do I properly call xpoint, ypoint, zpoint?

Inet.cs

```
public class inet : MonoBehaviour
{
    ShowMessage show = new ShowMessage();
    CecepMessageRecvJob Receiver;


    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Receiver = new CecepMessageRecvJob("tcp://localhost:6567", false, true, "afrl.cmasi.AirVehicleState");
        Receiver.MessageEncode += show.OnMessageEncoded;

        Receiver.Start();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        Receiver.MessageEncode -= show.OnMessageEncoded;
        Receiver.Abort();
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    float speed = 90.0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed * 0.5f;



        speed -= transform.forward.y * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.Rotate(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 5.0f);

        float terrainHeightWhereWeAre = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(transform.position);

        if (terrainHeightWhereWeAre > transform.position.y)
        {
            Vector3 temp = new Vector3(xpoint,ypoint,zpoint);
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,
                terrainHeightWhereWeAre,
                transform.position.z);
        }
    }
}
```

ShowMessages.cs

```
public class ShowMessage 
{

    public void OnMessageEncoded(object source, NetMQMessage message)

    {
        try
        {
            string messJson = message[1].ConvertToString();

            PlayerState stateMsg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlayerState>(messJson);
            //Console.WriteLine($"ID: {stateMsg.ID}, Latitude: {stateMsg.Location.Latitude}");



            idNine = $"{stateMsg.ID}";
            if (planeNine == stateMsg.ID)
            {
                Debug.Log($"You Did it right bud ID: {stateMsg.ID}, Latitude: {stateMsg.Location.Latitude}, Longitude: {stateMsg.Location.Longitude},Altitude: {stateMsg.Location.Altitude}");
                double xpoint = stateMsg.Location.Latitude;
                double zpoint = stateMsg.Location.Longitude;
                double ypoint = stateMsg.Location.Altitude;

                return ;   
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Log(" fix me: This means an Issue." + ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you will be able to in your current setup. I believe you should be returning a vector3 values in OnMessageEncoded(...) or passing another callback to pass those values around.

Comment: I had to create it within OnMessageEncoded(…). I appreciate your help!